# in iOS7 how do you stop the First viewcontroller autorotating?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have an app that just needs one screen to autorotate, the first and last screens should be portrait. I can get the last screen to stop rotating using:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

But this does not work on the first screen, I am using a storyboard with a `UINavigationController` (I'm thinking that may have something to do with it?)

Any help would be gratefully received. Thanks

Comment: the `UINavigationController` basically does not care about its individual `UIViewController` classes' orientation wish. it uses its own settings for supporting orinetations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to subset the `UINavigationController` and you should use it instead of the standard `UINavigationController`.

I have done this in my projects, so this cares of the individual `UIViewController` classes' custom orientations:

## .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIOrientationController : UINavigationController { }
@end
```

## .m

```
@implementation UIOrientationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

@end
```

*NOTE: you can extended this class with overriding more methods, if it becomes a requirement in your final code.*