# Override Autorotation Property of 3rd Party ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app that makes use of a third party library that presents its own view controller. All that is available to me is a .a library and a header file. My app only runs in portrait mode but when I have the phone in a landscape orientation and present the view controller from the library, the app crashes with an error stating that:

"No supported orientation matches that of the application."

My guess is that they have written the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate { 
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    // ATTENTION! Only return orientation MASK values
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

If that is the case, I will likely need to override those methods to tell the OS not to rotate and that only portrait is supported. **How can I go about doing this?**

The only possibility I can think of is to swizzle the method for that view controller but this seems like a dangerous approach according to a couple of SO posts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in iOS7 how do you stop the First viewcontroller autorotating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239641/in-ios7-how-do-you-stop-the-first-viewcontroller-autorotating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always do the following (as an example of locking a ViewController in Portrait mode):

1) Setup a property on your application delegate header file ... `@property (nonatomic) BOOL lockScreenPortraitOnly;`

2) In the application delegate implementation file add the following method:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindows:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (!self.lockScreenPortraitOnly)
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;   // or, whatever you wish to support
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

3) From within your ViewController add the following:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    ((EliotsApplicationDelegateType *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).lockScreenPortraitOnly = YES;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    ((EliotsApplicationDelegateType *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).lockScreenPortraitOnly = NO;
}
```

Now, it doesn't matter what's in Plist or what a 3rd party library is doing as the "window" is the most root, and as such, it controls everything else in the hierarchy.  Obviously in my example it is assumed that your VC is invoked before your 3rd-party library code gets spun up (adjust, season, and bake as needed).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go ahead and swizzle it. You'll need to be careful when upgrading the library to test this particular item. The danger in swizzling usually comes with swizzling Apple's APIs as they can be deprecated or their behaviour changed at any release (which could subsequently break your app for users).